# Thymeleaf 3 #request object is null in inline Javascript

Tags: thymeleaf

I have below code in a web page in Spring Boot 2 web app:

```
<div data-th-fragment="head-section">
<div> blah </div>
<script data-th-inline="javascript">
  var url = [[${#request.requestURL} ]];
  var country = [[${#locale.country}]]

  </script>

</div>
```

Thymeleaf throws error that says cannot get requestURL on null while it correctly gets the locale. Thymeleaf 3 official documentation says #request and #locale  are valid objects in web context.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried retrieving a request parameter, like so, just for testing, and does it also fail? ${#request.getParameter('q')}

Comment: Are you sure you're using Thymeleaf 3?  Your example worked for me when  I tried it.  Does `var url = [[${#httpServletRequest.requestURL}]];` work?

Comment: Thank you for comments. Yes I tried that. From stacktrace it is thymeleaf version 3.0.9. both #request and httpServletRequest are null.

Answer (score 2):

Just [Metroids](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4126893/metroids) mention and Refer to Spring boot getting started [Securing a Web Application](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) User #httpServletRequest is not null. is an instance of [HttpServletRequestWrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```